# Parse ISO-date with lower specificity

Tags: java, java-time, iso8601, localdate

I am trying to parse ISO8601-compliant strings that only specify the date up to a certain point, for example `2018-02` for February 2018, skipping the day.

The `java.time` package seems to fail to parse such strings. I have tried the following:

```
Instant.parse("2018-02");
LocalDateTime.parse("2018-02")
LocalDate.parse("2018-02", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

which fail with the following error

> DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-02' could not be parsed at index 7

I also tried the following, though I don't actually want to specify the exact pattern and just accept everything ISO8601-compliant:

```
LocalDate.parse("2018-02", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM"));
```

which fails with:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-02' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=2, Year=2018},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Is there a way to parse such ISO8601-strings with the `java.time` package?

Comment: Well, a date is a _day_ and not a _month_ ... - You could just assume one day, e.g. the first, and append that to the date string you get.

Comment: Are your strings always like that, or is it a requirement to parse `2018-02`, `2018-02-15`, `2018-02-15T12`, etc.?

Comment: Technically I only need to parse `yyyy-MM`, but I'd like to if I could make it robust by accepting any ISO8601-date, including `yyyy-MM-dd` and time-parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [the `YearMonth` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/class-use/YearMonth.html):

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse("2018-02");
```

(the input is in ISO format so no need to provide a formatter here).

---

**UPDATE**

In the comment, you indicate that the input could be `2018-02` or `2018-02-01`, in which case you want to ignore the day. In that case, you can use:

```
//note the optional day
DateTimeFormatter FMT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM[-dd]");

YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(FMT.parseBest(input, YearMonth::from, LocalDate::from));
```

Comment: Works for me, but is there a way to get a `YearMonth` instance by parsing arbitrary ISO8601 local dates? This fails for `2018-02-01` or more precision, which is a possible input if somone decides to output month-precise dates as full-precision ISO8601-dates

Comment: I suggest you clarify your question - what output do you want in that case? A LocalDate? Do you also want a LocalDate when the input is `2018-02`? In that case,  what day should it use?

Comment: I want a `YearMonth`. It should discard unnecessary precision